# How to configure cassandra on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I read most of the tutorials how to install cassandra in ec2 but I am very confused about the paths they recommend to store the data. In my ec2 instances my partitions are like below. Note: my rootfs is very small only 6GB.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          6.0G  5.5G  513M  92% /
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
devtmpfs         15G     0   15G   0% /dev
securityfs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs            15G  4.0K   15G   1% /dev/shm
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs            15G   17M   15G   1% /run
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
configfs           0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
/dev/xvda2      6.0G  5.5G  513M  92% /
selinuxfs          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/selinux
systemd-1          0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
debugfs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
mqueue             0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
hugetlbfs          0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
```

So in the instructions it tells me I should store data in `/var/lib/cassandra/data` directory. But what am I going to do with the rest of the partitions ? I have enough space in other partitions but not much in rootfs. If I store in `/var/lib/cassandra` my rootfs become full in few minutes.

Can someone please help me, what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a secondary drive with enough disk space. Usually you want to use an ephemeral drive, since this is the fastest drive. If you don't have any then you've chosen a wrong instance type. Then you can either modify the data paths in the `cassandra.yaml`, or simply recreate the folder structure on that data drive and create symbolic links to them - so your `/var/lib/cassandra/data` will point to `/data0/cassandra/data`. I prefer symbolic links because you don't need to remember all different configs and can always start your journey on the server from the standard entry points.

Data0 here is just a mount point for your device. Does not have to be data0. Usually the instance comes with 1 or more ephemeral drives and you choose either to use them individually or make a raid out of them. Once you have it all done you mount them somewhere. Can be anything you like.

Comment: Thanks Roman, Can you please explain me little bit on what is /data0 by looking at my df command output above.

Comment: Just added comment. This is just a mount point name for your ephemeral storage. Can be anything you like